# Adding extra button for sample product to Magento product page

Tags: php, magento

I have website to sell fabrics and I want to allow user to order sample of each product.
so for this I want to add an extra button for allowing user to add the sample product of the 
corrosponding product like in this other website (**check order swatch @ $0.5**)

http://fabricandsewing.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=1286&&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Price for each product sample will be same $0.5

How could I achieve this in my magento website.Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what to try. I can modify code and add extra button but I am not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create one additional sample product in your catalog for such product, providing similar product details and price for this sample product. I will keep SKU of this sample product as if myproductsku is the SKU of main product then its sample product's SKU will be myproductsku-sample so that it will be easy to recognize that to which product a sample product belogs.

Then we need to linkup both these product. It can be done via cross-sell products or up-sell products, but I will avoid both these methods so that I am not harming any default use of such linking. I am creating a custom attribute sample_product_id which will contain product_id of my sample product and finally write below code in {theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml near `Add to Cart` button.

```
<?php 
    if($_product->getSampleProductId()): 
        $_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getSampleProductId(), 'price', Mage::app()->getStore()); 
        $_formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_price, true, false);
        $_buttonTitle = "Order Sample @".$_formattedPrice;
?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $_buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/product/'.$_product->getSampleProductId()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $_buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I will try these both methods and will mark appropriate ans. Thanks

Comment: @Deependra Singh This might be a stupid question.. but what does **getSampleProductId()** reference.. i searched through all Magento 1.8.1 core files and could not find that method.. any idea on where and what it references.. thanks!

Comment: @Pritesh, were you able to get this solution to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can add a button on your product page that allows you to place order for a sample by passing its attribute, when you click on this button, the attribute fetched the details of the product you can setup the price to what you want and add it to your cart as a product, for a descriptive and point to point walkthrough...

```
http://opensourcetalking.com/magento/magento-free-samples-solution.html
```

Comment: This is very useful link to demonstrate that how to create product and add to cart on fly but I will not recommend this solution here, as it has a flaw that every time it will create a new product hence ending up lots unnecessary products in catalog.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will check your and deependra solution and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: The link above is dead. Is there an updated link to this info?